# PHP - sending very long string via POST

Tags: php

I have a textarea and very long string (binary data eg: 01 11 21 ...). When I send this data via POST method I don't get a full data. After submit form I check this variable via `strlen` and I always get 1047572 size. Can I increase this limit? I tried with `ini_set('memory_limit')` but it didn't work. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You might want to check the `post_max_size` setting in the INI file. It might be limited to 1MB

Comment: @GuidoFaecke post_max_size I have set at 512M